# How to send sequential requests with comlex logic in send function in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I've got a complex logic in my sendForm function, which allows me to send more then 2 requests at the same time. I want to make my requests to be sent sequentially, one after another. And if previous request returns "bad request" or some other error, then next request should not be sent. Forkjoin isn't my choice because it sends request in parallel. I tried to use combineLatest operator, but it returns only the last values. Any suggestions?

```
sendForm() {
    const team = toFormData(this.form.controls.profile.value);

    // First request
    this.teamService.sendTeam(team).subscribe(() => console.log('TEAM UPDATED'));

    // 2nd Block with requests
    this.form.controls.members.value.map((m, index) => {
      const member = toFormData(m);

      if (m.id) {
        this.teamService.updateMember(member, m.id).subscribe(() => {
        console.log('MEMBER UPDATED');
        });
      } else {
         this.teamService.createMember(member).subscribe(() => console.log('MEMBER CREATED'));
      }
    });

    // 3rd Block with requests
    this.form.controls.drinks.value.map((d, index) => {
      const drink = toFormData(d);

      if (d.id) {
        this.teamService.updateDrink(drink, d.id).subscribe(() => {
        console.log('DRINK UPDATED');
        });
      } else {
         this.teamService.createDrink(drink).subscribe(() => console.log('DRINK CREATED'));
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: Have a look at concatMap: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/concatMap

Comment: By `I want to make my requests to be sent sequentially`, you mean that each **block** of requests should be made sequentially, or literally every request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to build pipes with `concat`:

```js
sendForm() {
  const team = toFormData(this.form.controls.profile.value);

  // First request
  this.teamService.sendTeam(team).pipe(

    // once team has been sent does this block
    // concat makes a sequence
    concatMap(() => {
      const tasks$ = [];

      // 2nd Block with requests
      for (const m of this.form.controls.members.value) {
        const member = toFormData(m);
        if (m.id) {
          tasks$.push(this.teamService.updateMember(member, m.id));
        } else {
         tasks$.push(this.teamService.createMember(member));
        }
      }

      // 3rd Block with requests
      for (const d of this.form.controls.drinks.value) {
      const drink = toFormData(d);
      if (d.id) {
        tasks$.push(this.teamService.updateDrink(drink, d.id));
      } else {
        tasks$.push(this.teamService.createDrink(drink));
      }

      // using concat for the tasks.
      return tasks$.length ? concat(...tasks$) : EMPTY;
    }),

  ).subscribe();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I made it as your example, but only the first request was sent. Tasks$.length is equal to 4.

Comment: Aha, then it means update and create don't complete. is it expected and they should emit more than once?

Comment: I've updated the answer with `take(1)`, let me know if you expect more than 1 emit from them and we'll fine a solution.

Comment: yeah, I expect more than one value

Comment: Aha, then wait a bit please.

Comment: Might you explain how it should work in your case, for example `createMember` is called, in which case it emits the 1st value and the 2nd one?

Comment: I have a form in which you can add up to 3 members in team. The form can be saved as a draft and can be edited after saving. If user add a member for the first time, I should use createMember method, and if the member is already existed, for example, the info about member was saved on previous session, then I should call update member. 
For example user create 3 members in first session, then memberCreate method invokes 3 times. On the second session user can change info about members, then updateMember method invokes 3 times and so one.

Comment: This sounds like one call should cause one emit. Please try the updates solution with take one. Quite sure it does what you need.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot